# Как транспонировать список?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Как мне получить из этого:

```
lst = [['1', '2', '3'],
       ['4', '5', '6']]
```

получить это:

```
[['1', '4'], ['2', '5'], ['3', '6']]
```

?

Comment: `list(map(list, zip(*lst)))`.

Comment: к сортировке не имеет никакого отношения

Comment: Не помню, а разве `list(zip(*lst))` не сработает?

Comment: @AndyPavlov получится список кортежей, а не список списков

Comment: @Danis А, точно только это) Тогда мэпим)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new_lst = list(map(list, zip(*lst)))
```